# What is meant by "still alive in kicking"?

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context

Today I'd like to ask about an expression I heard on Youtube.

I couldn't hear it clearly but a comedian said "***He was still alive in kicking***" (<-- this part is what I am not sure about)

The story was that one guy has a friend who has some problems in his muscles so that he is not able to move his body properly ( a disabled person). Those who have the same problem, mostly die before 20 years old. But the guy found him still alive (actively)

So the comedian said "he was still alive in kicking"

Did I get it correctly?

Comment: "Did you mean: still alive and kicking?" –Google

Answer (score 2):

The correct idiom is

> **alive and kicking**
>   Fig. well and healthy. *Jane: How is Bill since his illness last month? Mary: Oh; he's alive and kicking.*
>   [- thefreedictionary.com](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/alive+and+kicking)